C++ <filesystem> compiles but doesn't run (VSCode only)
I can't run any code that uses the filesystem library in c++ using vscode, or even the terminal, but everything works in visual studio.
I just wanted to write some code using the filesystem library in c++, i've made sure to have my minGW in PATH and that my c++ version is 17 or greater. I'm currently using this command to compile my file
g++ -std=c++20 -lstdc++fs main.cpp -o main


it compiles successfully but when i try to run it using
./main

it gives says in the vscode terminal that the command failed.

BUT on Visual Studio everything works perfectly. Can anybody help me?
this is the code if it you can find it helpful
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main(){
    fs::create_directory("test");
    std::cout << "hello world!";
    return 0;
}

and when i try to debug it it gives this error in the debug console
ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139.


GCC is picky with the order of sources, objects and libraries when you build. Always put libraries (the -l options) last on the command line. The only thing that would make the build not fail, is if you're using a new enough GCC where the stdc++fs library isn't needed.

Also please [edit] your question to show us the exact and actual terminal output. Copy-paste it as text into your question, from the command you try to run to the end of the output and the next prompt.

there's no output that's the thing, it simply doesn't do nothing wait i'll add the photo of what i see

In a terminal, type ldd main.exe. What output do you get?

after ldd main.exe i see this:
    ntdll.dll => /c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ffd5dbb0000)
    KERNEL32.DLL => /c/Windows/System32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7ffd5bc40000)     
    KERNELBASE.dll => /c/Windows/System32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7ffd5b420000) 
    ucrtbase.dll => /c/Windows/System32/ucrtbase.dll (0x7ffd5b950000)     
    libgcc_s_seh-1.dll => /mingw64/bin/libgcc_s_seh-1.dll (0x7ffd4c110000)
    msvcrt.dll => /c/Windows/System32/msvcrt.dll (0x7ffd5bd90000)
    libstdc++-6.dll => /mingw64/bin/libstdc++-6.dll (0x7ffd05b30000)

i get an error on KERNEL22.dll

You have both ucrtbase.dll and msvcrt.dll linked in. That's weird. Normally you have either one or the other. There are msvcrt builds of gcc, and there are ucrt builds. Perhaps you have both kinds in the path, or some other sort of mix-and-match error. I would recommend completely uninstalling and reinstalling MinGW. After an uninstall, make sure you have absolutely no gcc anywhere in your path.

okay i will try it later now i have to go. I will keep you updated

You don't need -lstdc++fs in modern GCC. Also try compiling and running directly from MSYS2 terminal.

btw it still doesn't work, i had to go on visual studio code to work with filesystem lmao
